# How to say Hibernate to throw Exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.4 with Hibernate. Now I have noticed a problem. I have already created a bug report https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-5444. But what I wonder more is that Hibernate / Spring Boot does not abort the start when SQL errors occur.

In the concrete case it is so, that a table in MariaDB was not created. But the application starts normally, you only see the error in the log if you search for it.

But what is even worse, when I create an object which should be saved in this table and save it with `save()`, there is not even an execution. Nothing at all. So I cannot determine that the record was not saved at all. Can I set somewhere that Hibernate should throw exceptions here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue. Spring Boot aborts startup if an exception during the initialization of the database occurs. Unless you have configured it to continue on error. Using this property:

```
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
```

What could happen is that your database driver did not throw any exception at all. In that case Spring Boot won't notice the error.